# Unit Test DbContext.UseInMemoryDatabase With Parallel Threads

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing

I'm having an issue I'm trying to isolate and debug. First trying to create a unit test that reproduces it: PayPal returns 2 types of responses, and sometimes at the exact same time which results in double-processing -- been chasing that bug for a long while.

So I'm trying to setup a test where I'm processing 2 requests simultaneously.

The problem I have is that I get this:

> A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext

Indeed, the test database gets created like this

```cs
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PaymentsContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
if (_output != null)
{
    builder = builder.LogTo(_output.WriteLine);
}
var db = new PaymentsContext(builder.Options);
db.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

The in-memory database is the DbContext itself, and the DbContext cannot be called by multiple threads simultaneously. In production, each request has its own DbContext pointing to the same database so there's no problem.

Is there a way to write the test I need?

Comment: Why do you need to reproduce it in tests? Instead try to mitigate the problem by ensuring that only one thread handles particular requests or implement idem-potency, setup row versioning on db an EF level to get an exception on 2nd attempt.

Comment: I've tried setting a lock for now; hopefully it's at the right place this time. It's recommended practice to first write a test to reproduce a bug, and then work on it until the test passes. That way you're sure the bug will never ever come back. Particularly if I want a solution that doesn't require a lock, I'd need to be able to test it to make sure it works. Otherwise the only way to know whether it works is to push into production and cross fingers, which failed a few times already.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is a solution to this? Perhaps this should be an Integration Test instead of a Unit Test; with a real database. That should work; if I want to take the time to set it up.